# Trying to split a dataframe column based on the values of another column line per line

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I have some IDnumbers (df index) with test score information. Each test is comprised of sub tests. All of the SubTest scores are in the same field and there is an other field that tells you the test type (i.e. the delimitor). Say for example I have the GRE. The GRE has three subtests: Verbal, Analytical Writing, and Quantitative. One Field has the Test Type (GRE) and another field has the Test Score Values in one field (GRE Verbal 156.0/170.0 GRE Analytical Writing 4.5/6.0 GRE Quantitative 157.0/170.0). There are multiple other tests in this data set of the same structure. I want to use the Test Type column to act as the delimitor of the .split method on the Test Score Values field and have expand = True but it never works... I keep getting a key error.

I've tried a lot of different approaches (many of them from similar questions on stackoverflow that don't match my issue exactly):

1.)

```py
df[['Score1', 'Score2', 'Score3','Score4','Score5']] = [x.split(df['Delimiter'], n = 5, expand=True) for x in df['Test Score Values']]
```

This resulted in a "KeyError:  Delimiter"

2.)

```py
df[['Score1', 'Score2', 'Score3','Score4','Score5']] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Test Score Values'].str.split(df['Delimiter'], n = 5, expand=True))
```

This resulted in "KeyError: ('Test Score Values', 'occurred at index ID')"

3.)

```py
df[['Score1', 'Score2', 'Score3','Score4','Score5']] = df['Test Score Values'].split(df['Delimiter'], n = 5, expand=True)
```

This resulted in "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'"

4.)

```py
df['Test Score Values'].apply(lambda x: x.split(x['Delimiter'],expand=True))
```

This resulted in "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

I keep getting Errors but what I would like to get, in keeping with the GRE example at the beginning is something along the lines of.

```
ID     Delimiter               TestScoreValues
1         GRE        GRE Verbal 156.0/170.0 GRE Analytical Writing 4.5/6.0 GRE Quantitative 157.0/170.0      

Score1                   Score2                                    Score 3
Verbal 156.0/170.0      Analytical Writing 4.5/6.0           Quantitative 157.0/170.0
```

I then would want to break them down further but solving this split would be a good first step because afterwards I can split on the space within the different scores.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: how about:     `pd.DataFrame([x.split(y) for x,y in zip(df['TestScoreValues'], df['Delimeter'])])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For highly specific manipulations, I recommend `for` loops given their flexibility and readability (though I will stress that this isn't automatically the most optimized way to do this sort of thing).

First, initialize your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

s = {'Test Type':'GRE',
     'Test Score':'GRE Verbal 156.0/170.0 GRE Analytical Writing 4.5/6.0 GRE Quantitative 157.0/170.0',
    }

df = pd.DataFrame([s])

print(df.head())
#
#                                          Test Score Test Type
# 0  GRE Verbal 156.0/170.0 GRE Analytical Writing ...       GRE
```

Next, iterate over your df and perform necessary string manipulations:

```
new_values = []

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
  scores = row['Test Score'].split(row['Test Type'])
  for s in scores:
    # You don't want the blank items
    if s!='':
      s = s.strip().split()
      # get the section and the score for each
      section, score_actual = ' '.join(s[:-1]),s[-1]
      new_values.append({
          'Test': row['Test Type'],
          'Section':section,
          'Score': score_actual})

df_new = pd.DataFrame(new_values)
print(df_new.head())
#
#          Score             Section Test
# 0  156.0/170.0              Verbal  GRE
# 1      4.5/6.0  Analytical Writing  GRE
# 2  157.0/170.0        Quantitative  GRE
```

You could go a step further and begin manipulating each row down to its percent score, or create a new table with maximum score for each section per exam but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Yaakov, This is very helpful! I thought about doing a for loop but I'm new at this and this worked exactly as I wanted.  Thanks so much!